# Finding and changing the value of a single "href" value using Simple Html DOM Library

Tags: php

i need help in parsing a href attribute of a single anchore tag and then changing its value in a php file using "simple html dom" library. 
Below is the html code:-

```
<li id="toggle"> <a id="open" class="open" href="#" style="display: block; "></a></li>
```

Now i want to get this specific href value and change it to some page like say, Logout.php depending upon if the user is logged in or not.
And here is my php code:

```
<?php 
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    session_start();
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('index1.php');
     if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
       $ret = $html->find('li[id=hello]');
       $ret = "Hello Guest";
       $tog = $html->find('li[id=toggle]');
       $tog = "Log In | Register";
     }else{
         $user = $_SESSION['username'];
         $ret = "Hello " . $user;
         $tog = "Log out";
         $hrf = $html->find('a[id=open]');
         $hrf->href = 'Logout.php';
      }
  ?>
```

Now except finding and changing the "href" value, all other things are working properly. 
Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i was able to solve the problem. i think both of we overlooked the fact that it was returning an array. So this is what i did to solve. May it help some one else also.

```
$e = $html->find('a[id=open]'); // returns an array containing all the info for anchor a
$link = $e[0]->href; //the value of attribute href of anchor a which was the first element       in array
$e[0]->href = 'Logout.php'; // get the new value
$link = $e[0]->href; // assign the value to a variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it all in the [Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
$tog = $html->find('li[id=toggle]');

$tog->innertext = "Log In | Register";
```

when you echo the content. the item will have the new value

UPDATE

You can get the href this way:

EDIT:

```
//$hrf = $html->find('a[id=open]');
$hrf = $html->find('#open'); // this makes more sense since it has an ID
$oldlink = $hrf->href; // this will retrieve the href value;
$hrf->href = 'Logout.php'; // new link
```

Comment: Here exactly i am asking how to get the "href" attribute value from the html i shown above and change it. All the other things are working and i can echo them properly. thank you.

Comment: @Ibu, i want to change the "href" value in the above <a id="open" class="open" href="#" style="display: block; "></a> tag. How to do that. This Log in | Register is working properly. No issue here. thank you

Comment: @Ibu, sorry i posted without seeing your update. checking now. inform you after checking it. thank you.

Comment: @Ibu, its not working. I am getting errors like "trying to get property of non-object and assigning values to non-object. :-(

Comment: the only reason it wouldnt work is if the element is not present. [See this part in the Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_access_attr)

Comment: as i am new to php, i couldnt understand it. The element 'a' and the attribute 'href' is very well present as you can see in the HTML code snippet i posted above. :-(

Comment: @Hem, Good call for the answer i had paid attention that you are selecting an element with the ID, i have edited my code to select by ID so it returns a single element